# Blazor server side extended validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want my validation model to be invalid when the entered value for ActionId **is not** within in array/list of integers

```
public class AddTerminalInput
{
    private List<int> actionIds;
    public AddTerminalInput(List<int> actionIds)
    {
        this.actionIds = actionIds;
    }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string TerminalId { get; set; } = "";
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string TerminalName { get; set; } = "";

    // ActionId should be only valid if the value is within actionIds
    public int ActionId { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

does anybody know how I can achive this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library on nuget for Blazor & FluentValidation, that will do it.

Comment: Actually I was thinking https://github.com/mrpmorris/blazor-validation because it lets you use both DataAnnotations and FluentValidation at the same time - but I didn't want to blow my own trumpet :)

Comment: Fair, I just thought that answer should contain a link so I posted the one I know. I did not know about your library.